# Getting ArgMax of a 2d Array

Tags: python, numpy, argmax

so my questions is pretty straight forward. I have a 3-d array and would like to get the maximal value alone the first two axes.

```
import numpy as np
array = np.zeros((3,3,2))
array[1][1][0] = 1
array[1][1][1] = 2
```

How do I now check along [1][1] which value has the max value? I would suspect to use np.argmax() but I googled for ages and could not find a working solution. Thank you in advance!

To be clear, I want my return to be 2, just a single integer.

Comment: are you looking to find the max value for just this case or any slice in general, like `array[i][j]`?

Comment: Your expected output of `2` is the maximum *value*, not the *argument of the maximum* ("argmax") value. Do you actually expect to get the coordinates along the first two dimensions *of* the maximum value, which would be `(1, 1)`?

Comment: Actually, re-reading your question, if you are looking for the argument in the last axis that points to the maximum value, you can use `array[1,1,:].argmax()`

Comment: Sorry I was working. I expect to find the max value for any value in the array, like the top comment said array[i][j]. I want to compare all values for the z axis and return the one that has the biggest value. In the example I want as an input the first two axes [i][j] and then check for all possible values that the third axes can be [z]. In the example: [1][1][0] and [1][1][1] and since the second has a higher value I want that as return

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For what you describe, you could just do:

```
array[1,1].max()
```

which will return 2. If you instead wanted the maximum value along the last axis for every combination of the first two axes, you would do:

```
array.max(axis=-1)
```

which in your case will return a 3x3 array of the maximum values along the last axis:

```
[[0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 2. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0.]]
```

If you want the *indices* of the maximum value, you would instead use `argmax`, just like you would `max` above:

```
array[1,1].argmax()
```

which in this case returns just `1`. You would then have to append that to `(1,1)` to get the complete index to the maximum value in your original array (ie `(1,1,1)`).

Comment: That works perfectly, thanks a lot! Really appreciate it.

Comment: If the answer fixed your problem, you should [mark it as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Sorry I didnt know. Thank you!